# How to connect widget to custom signal declared in one class while being inside of another class

Tags: python, pyqt

**Short description:**
There are two Threads declared along with seven queue items. For each queue item there was QProgressBar created and an instance of it was assigned to each queue item using queue's `setValue()` method. Inside of Thread's `run()` method QProgressBar instance is retrieved using queue item's `get()` method. While still inside of `run()` method QProgressBar instance is connected to a custom "updateBar" signal so a Progress Bar widget could be updated from inside of running `run()` method (or from any other Thread's method). While code seems to be running fine I would like to get your opinion if I did right thing connecting QProgressBar instance to Signal while being outside of MyWindow class (connection to signal was made inside of Thread Class). Are there any complications to the approach I implemented. Or should I use something else?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import Queue as queue

class PbWidget(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PbWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(100)        
        self._active = False  

    def update_bar(self, argValue):
        self.setValue(argValue)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active = False

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            pb = self.queue.get()
            pb.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateBar"), pb.update_bar)
            for i in range(0,11):
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateBar"), i*10) 
                self.sleep(1) 
            self.queue.task_done()
            pb.disconnect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateBar"), pb.update_bar)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(cWidget)
        button=QtGui.QPushButton("Sumbit Threads")
        button.clicked.connect(self.submitThreads)
        self.layout.addWidget(button)

    def submitThreads(self):
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(1, 3): 
            thread = MyThread(self.queue)
            self.threads.append(thread)            
            thread.start()

        numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        for number in numbers:
            pb=PbWidget()
            self.layout.addWidget(pb)
            self.queue.put(pb) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(300, 30)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have this running, I don't see why you would change.

Personally, I would NOT pass objects (i.e., the progress widgets) between threads, because this won't scale to multiprocessing, clusters, etc., and not be able to get/set the same variable from different threads at the same time.

The alternative I use is to pass simple status messages, and have a QTimer in the main thread regularly check the incoming queue (with get_nowait() ), and set the interface appropriately.

e.g., set up a timer on GUI init:

```
    self.timer = QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
    self.timer.start(100)
```

and in the timeout method:

```
    coming = self.incoming.get_nowait()
```

where `incoming` is a Queue that the other thread/process(es) can write to. In your case, the data would contain a progress bar identifier and the progress value. The get_nowait will raise an empty exception when there is no data waiting.

As a matter of interest, what happens if you invoke pb.update_bar() directly, rather than use the signal mechanism?

Comment: 'pb.update_bar()` was causing irregular crashes with Q complains I've never seen before. A quick google search and a first suggestion was not to try to set the progress bar widget directly from a Thread's `run()` method. Please post some example on how to use `get_nowait()` in situation like this. It is interesting to know.